# Mailchimp Error: -100 when using node-mailchimp API in a Meteor app

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, meteor, mailchimp

I am trying to use [meteor-mailchimp](https://github.com/MiroHibler/meteor-mailchimp/) which in turn uses [node-mailchimp](https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-mailchimp) to subcribe an email to a mailing list

but when I call lists/subscribe I keep getting a Error: -100 "You must specify a email"

```
apiKey = "234324234234324324234234"
listId = 
    id : "234234234"
email = -> 
    email: 'example@gmail.com'

MailChimpAPI = new MailChimp(
    apiKey
    version: '2.0'
)

MailChimpAPI.call "lists", "subscribe", listId, email, (error,data)->
    return
```

I am fairly certain it is the way I am formatting the email arguement passed to the api call but I can't figure it out how to do it correctly.

If i make it an object:

```
email = 
    email: example@gmail.com
```

it complains its not a function

when I make it a function that returns and object (as above) still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, and yes I am an idiot. All of the options must be passed as a single object, so the configuration and call needs to be:

```
options = 
    id : "234234234"
    email :
        email: 'example@gmail.com'

MailChimpAPI.call "lists", "subscribe", options (error,data)->
    return
```